# How to Trigger Event when Join Operation on Kafka Streams Does Not Complete

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have 3 Kafka Streams for 3 different topics. To each of these streams I apply a filter operation so that I can filter results that contain a certain field which is the type of message.

Right now I have three streams that are the result of applying the filter operation which we'll call Stream A, Stream B and Stream C.

I join the messages from each Stream by key by applying a join operation between Stream A and Stream B and then I get the result (Stream A + Stream B) and join that with Stream C (Messages on Stream C usually show up much later that A and B because the producer takes longer to produce those messages)

What I want to know is how can I trigger an event (To signal an error) when one of the 3 required messages fails to appear within a defined time window? So lets say I want to join messages from Streams A and B and the message from Stream A appears but the one from Stream B does not or both of them appear but then Stream C message does not. How can I signal that a certain message from a certain Stream failed to appear within the given time window?

Below you can find the code I have that is working for the best case scenario which is all messages appear within the time window.

```
//Filter the Streams to get only records corresponding to report of type FULL REPORT
KStream<String, String> filteredStreamA = StreamA.filter((reportId, jsonPayload) -> filterRecordsByReportType(jsonPayload));

KStream<String, String> filteredStreamB = StreamB.filter((reportId, jsonPayload) -> filterRecordsByReportType(jsonPayload));

KStream<String, String> filteredStreamC = StreamC.filter((reportId, jsonPayload) -> filterRecordsByReportType(jsonPayload));

//Inner Join of the Streams A and B by Key during a 30 seconds window
KStream<String, String> joinedAandBStream = filteredStreamA
                .join(filteredStreamB, A_B_joiner, JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(30)));

//Inner Join of the Streams (A+B) and C during a 60 seconds window
KStream<String, String> joinedAandBandC = joinedAandBStream
                .join(filteredStreamC, A_B_C_joiner, JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(60)));
```

Comment: Perhaps you could use `leftJoin`, and then `.split(...).branch(...)` based on values in B being empty in the join result. This would then separate the matched A-B pairs from the unmatched A's. Then you can process the unmatched pairs separately - same for the second join.